# Order of arguments and Table function output in R

Tags: r

I have a silly question. Below is the output of a logistic regression analysis I did. I notice that when I switch the order of the arguments I put in the table function in R that it also switch the false positives and the false negatives values but it did not switch the the location of the Female and Male rows and columns. This to me seems like it could really affect the interpretation if the false positives/negatives can change just from the order the arguments are put into the table. I need to know which order output is correct and the proper order for placing arguments in the table function

[image: Table]

Comment: Well, what you have seen is correct. Basically, you are comparing the predict value to the actual value, meaning a female classified as male in predict is a false positive. But if you switch values, then it becomes a false negative, flipping the matrix across its diagonal.

Comment: To avoid confusion (no pun intended), you could label your inputs - `table(actual=c("m","f"), predicted=c("m","f"))` for instance.